# Apache Spark How aggregateby key works

Tags: java, apache-spark

I was playing with Spark. I am bit confused with the working of aggregateby key function.

If I provide non-zero initial value. It is adding 2*initial value in the total.

Following is the code snippet:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> mapToPair = rdd.mapToPair(message -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(message.split(",")[0], Integer.parseInt(message.split(",")[1])))

Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>  mergeValue =(v1, v2) -> v1+v2; Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>  mergeCombiners =(v1, v2) -> v1+v2;

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> aggregateByKey = mapToPair.aggregateByKey(1, mergeValue, mergeCombiners);

System.out.println("Aggregate by key "+ aggregateByKey.collect());
```

Following is my input rdd:

```
hello,1
hello,1
hello,1
hello,1
```

Output I am getting is

```
Aggregate by key [(hello,6)]
```

Please explain its working

Answer (score 2):

zeroValue is added every time new key is seen on current partition so it can be added as many times as many partitions you have and shouldn't change the result of merge and seq ops. This is why 0 is valid for addition but 1 is not.

Comment: What is the purpose of initialValue if it should always be zero?
If I am giving 0 , it is returning [(hello,4)] which is correct. However if I am giving it as 1 , I am expecting result to be [(hello,5)] however it is [(hello,6)].
It tried setting it as 2, then result becomes [(hello,8)]. So it adding 2*initialValue in the result which should not be the case

Comment: spark.default.parallelism for local mode of spark is the number of cores , hence assume that your PC has processor of 2 cores . so the default value is 2 .Hence merge Value called parallelly on the parallel distributed data leads to (defaultZero (1) + data sum (1+1)) + (defaultZero (1) + data sum (1+1))  =6 and not (defaultZero(1)+defaultZero(1+1+1+1)) that is 5

Comment: if you set  spark.default.parallelism to 1, it will yield a result of 5

Comment: It defines output type.

Comment: Tried setting spark.default.parallelism to 1
SparkConf conf =new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("TestRdd").set("spark.default.parallelism", "1");
But still same result

Comment: @Sourav local[2]  tells the spark to utilize  two cores for execution in local mode. So, could you please try with setMaster("local[1]") ?

Answer (score 1):

I  agree with @LostInOverflow and here is the explanation  why Spark has a **zeroValue** as first arugment in place in aggregateByKey:

Both 'merging values within a partition' (argument 2) and 'merging values betweeen partitions' (argument 3) functions read and update the first argument (zeroValue) and return it instead of creating a new return value to avoid extra memory allocation. This could be negligible for small scale operations but will be a memory saving technique for a very large scale operations running on cluster(s) with hundreds of nodes

Hence it will be an arbitrary value chosen based on the kind of operation performed in merge and combine to not to effect the actual result (0 for addition (or) 1 for multiplication)